# Where is add new option for uploading new theme in wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am facing problem in uploading a new downloaded theme in which is in .zip format.

I am new in wordpress.I created a new wordpress site from wordpress.com But can't find the add new option in the theme panel.

Where is that one? Every video shows the option add new but where is mine? or does it move away by the wordpress site recently?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your **WP-Admin Panel**
 Go to "**Design**" -> "**Themes**"-> "**Install**" or "**Add New**"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQDYK.jpg

Comment: Where is that Add new option in WP Admin panel ? is that in wordpress.com ?

I didn't find mine. Check this 

http://postimg.org/image/8b42s3qnb/

Answer (score 1):

Ok then lets get tricky and try this!

http://**www.your-site.com**/wp-admin/theme-install.php

If this does not work, search your FTP for
 the "theme-install.php" File
Maybe the File is corrupt or has been deleted?.